# Cut text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to cut text using jQuery? For example :

if output like :
`new/2016/songs1.mp3
 new/2015/songsx.mp3
 new/songs3.mp3`

Need output :

`songs1.mp3
 songsx.mp3
 songs3.mp3`

I want to put only file name with extension like `songs-name.mp3` not directory, so i want to cut this using jQuery.

Comment: use of **split** function of jQuery you can get the name of songs.

Comment: see updates............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split it and take the last item

```
var str = "new/2016/songs1.mp3";
var items = str.split( "/" );
alert(items[items.length - 1 ]);
```

or simply

```
alert( str.split("/").pop() );
```

if you want to remove the rest of the text then

```
var str = "new/2016/songs1.mp3";
var items = str.split( "/" );
str = items[items.length - 1 ];
```

or

```
str = str.split("/").pop();
```

Comment: should it remove all directory?

Comment: @user12345 check my answer again, you simply need to make it a function and call it with different `str`

Comment: i also want to cut `.mp3` how?

Comment: @user12345 split the final value by `.` and take the first item from the resulting array

Comment: Sorry i mean want to remove `.mp3`

Comment: @user12345  `str = str.split("/").pop().split( "." )[0];`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var filepath = "new/2015/songsx.mp3";
console.log(filepath.slice(filepath.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
```

Using the slice method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) you can get a part of a string.

Using the lastIndexOf method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) returns the index of the last occurrence of the given string (or -1 if given string does not occur in the string).

So what we are doing is getting the slice if the file path starting with the first character after the las "/" in the filepath variable.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how this code solves the question. This will help the OP and future searchers learn from your answer.

Comment: You're right, this needed more explanation. The answer should be more useful now.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out:
Here i use split function to split the string and then its return an array.

From that array we have to get the last portion i.e, Song name, So we have to get the length of that array.

After that we alert the array with the index of last portion.

```
var str = "new/2016/songs1.mp3";
var arr = str.split("/");
alert(arr[(arr.length) - 1]);
```